# Jasper Reports: How to combine two report streams into one PDF output?

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, inputstream

I have this code that only generates one Jasper report at a time to PDF based on a given condition.  But what if I want to combine both Jaspers into one PDF file? (i.e. the PDF output should be LoadTagR2R.jasper + LoadTagR2RLandscape.jasper -- which will be one PDF output stream with multiple pages)

```
        if (fullHalfTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){ //Read FULL_HALF_TAG value (if FULL_HALF_TAG == 'Y')
            logger.debug("Printing FULL tag...");
            reportStream = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/reports/LoadTagR2RLandscape.jasper");

        } else {
            logger.debug("Printing HALF tag...");
            reportStream = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/reports/LoadTagR2R.jasper");

        }

        //Report parameters
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        parameters.put("PLT_NO", pltNo);
        parameters.put("TICKET_NO", ticketNo);

          try {

             Connection conn = ConnectionUtils.getConnection();

             JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream,servletOutputStream, parameters, conn);
             response.setContentType("application/pdf");

             servletOutputStream.flush();
             servletOutputStream.close();
```

I have tried merging the two input streams as shown below but it didn't work.  Thoughts?

```
        new java.io.SequenceInputStream(s1, s2).
```

Comment: But I need to merge at the stream level before the PDF is generated by JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the old way to do this:

```java
JasperPrint jasperPrint1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportStream1,  parameters, conn);
JasperPrint jasperPrint2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportStream2,  parameters, conn);

List<JasperPrint> list = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
list.add(jasperPrint1);
list.add(jasperPrint2);

JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, list);
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,servletOutputStream); 
exporter.exportReport();
```

**EDIT:**

In [JasperReports 6.1.1 API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporterParameter.html) `JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST` and `JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM` are **deprecated** adding new method.

Replace:

```
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, list);
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,servletOutputStream);
```

with

```
exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(list));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(servletOutputStream));
```

Comment: Thanks but this is giving me an exception:  java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleWriterExporterOutput incompatible with net.sf.jasperreports.export.OutputStreamExporterOutput

Comment: use SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput (as in edited post)

Comment: How can I get the parameters of the report and the servletOutputStream?

Comment: @EyvindAlmqvist it is unclear what you mean with report, instead the stream is the stream your are writing the pdf to, hence it depends on use case.  See question for writing towards servletOutputStream (that's a java servlet stream to http client)

Comment: I just use these parameters: parameters.put("KEY", "Value"); Then I use a fake datasource, because there is no database connection. I get this error: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from InputStream.
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 25504446

Comment: Here are my output and input streams. Can I not use ByteArrayStreams? ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = reportService.createPDFReportOutStream(getReport());
  final ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outStream.toByteArray());

Comment: @EyvindAlmqvist With the SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput you can use any java.io.OutputStream (including ByteArrayOutputStream).  Your erros seems related to how you load the jasper print (maybe you are trying to load .jrxml and not the compiled .jasper) However I can't debug your code like this in comment sections, please ask a question un jasper-report tag, with a [mcve] and you can ping me here if you like me to look at the question (I'm not very active anymore, hence I do not monitor the tag actively)

Comment: I used Apache PDFBox instead. It was easier.