# jasper excel report how to merge multiple templates on one excell sheet

Tags: excel, jasper-reports

I have three different jasper templates that are merged together in one document. In excel they are placed each template on a separate sheet. Is it possible to change this behaviour so that all the three templates would be mergen on one sheet one after another?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33393400/jasper-reports-how-to-combine-two-report-streams-into-one-pdf-output using the JRXlsExporter and setting property  net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet  to false

Comment: XlsReportConfiguration.PROPERTY_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET in code.